# Python3 on Mac having trouble loading libssh2

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, python-venv, dyld

After getting updated to Monterey 12.2.1 and having Xcode updated to 13.2.1, I'm having trouble in a venv environment when I use the system installed Python, 3.10.2. My app is using ssh2-python, which needs to link to libssh2. I believe this spells it all out: (to skipg over the annoying horizontal scroll, the takeway text is `'/usr/lib/libssh2.1.dylib' (no such file)`

```
File "/Users/mnelson1/3m-install/venv-3.10.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pssh/clients/native/single.py", line 25, in <module>
    from ssh2.error_codes import LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/mnelson1/3m-install/venv-3.10.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ssh2/error_codes.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: /private/var/folders/6s/q3hjdt5s00b5p_cpjbbxp6680000gr/T/pip-install-lasr65mk/ssh2-python_46cfb4509bee4529bbe0e4eacbb00674/src/src/libssh2.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/mnelson1/3m-install/venv-3.10.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ssh2/error_codes.cpython-310-darwin.so
  Reason: tried: '/private/var/folders/6s/q3hjdt5s00b5p_cpjbbxp6680000gr/T/pip-install-lasr65mk/ssh2-python_46cfb4509bee4529bbe0e4eacbb00674/src/src/libssh2.1.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libssh2.1.dylib' (no such file)
```

Of course, libssh2 is actually installed:

```
❯ brew info libssh2
libssh2: stable 1.10.0 (bottled), HEAD
C library implementing the SSH2 protocol
https://www.libssh2.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/libssh2/1.10.0 (184 files, 999.8KB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2022-03-03 at 15:00:10
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/libssh2.rb
License: BSD-3-Clause
==> Dependencies
Required: openssl@1.1 ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
        Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 101,845 (30 days), 301,986 (90 days), 1,138,668 (365 days)
install-on-request: 1,683 (30 days), 6,573 (90 days), 137,389 (365 days)
build-error: 2 (30 days)

❯ ls -l /usr/local/lib/libssh*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 mnelson1  staff  44 Mar  3 15:01 /usr/local/lib/libssh2.1.dylib@ -> ../Cellar/libssh2/1.10.0/lib/libssh2.1.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 mnelson1  staff  38 Mar  3 15:01 /usr/local/lib/libssh2.a@ -> ../Cellar/libssh2/1.10.0/lib/libssh2.a
lrwxr-xr-x  1 mnelson1  staff  42 Mar  3 15:01 /usr/local/lib/libssh2.dylib@ -> ../Cellar/libssh2/1.10.0/lib/libssh2.dylib
```

(Although I'm concerned about that build-error - I'm weak here and don't know if this is a real problem or not.)

Anyway, I can work around this by setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH (currently undefined) to /usr/local/lib.

I'm not experienced at installation management on the Mac, so I'm wondering why a brew install of the library doesn't just work? Even more confusing, if I use 3.10.2 (or any other version) from pyeval, I don't have the problem. Why does the system install of Python apparently have a different dynamic library path from the pyeval builds?

I don't have any python modules installed in the global or local locations, so I don't think it's anything else I've done:

```
❯ pip3 list installed
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        22.0.3
setuptools 58.1.0
wheel      0.37.1
```

I thought that it's possible that old cached pip installs might need to be rebuilt, so I've tested by running my install after completely deleting the pip3 cache, to no avail.

The good news is that most of my target installs are on Linux systems, and they don't seem to have this fickleness about libssh2, so the problem is limited to my development environment. But I'd like to have a better idea of what I'm doing wrong. And there are a few app users who are likely vulnerable to this, and I'd like to be able to give a coherent explanation of any necessary workarounds.

Searching for info on this problem I realize it's not an uncommon problem, discussions like [this](https://github.com/lightbend/reactive-cli/issues/50) are scattered around, but the resolutions I've found don't enlighten things much for me.

Comment: Hey Mark. One request, please use the generic Python tag for all python related questions. Use an additional version-specific tag at your discretion. I would personally reserve that use for something specific about the differences between Python 2/ 3, Python 3 is the normal assumption now, IOW, Python *is* Python 3. Also, the generic Python tag gets much more traffic so more eyeballs on your question

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Any luck with this?

Comment: @ShlokaBhalgat here are my notes:

_The problem seemed to get fixed after I upgraded Xcode and the command line tools, AND rebooted, and erased the pip cache in ~/Library/Caches.

Just a guess, but one thing that I think happens is that I download a package that uses a library like libssh2, and it gets set up properly. But later when I update the O/S, either the lib changes location, or something is different, and the cached pip module is now pointing to bad locations.

Anyway, this can be resolved by setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib_

Comment: Okay. I recently upgraded to Montrey 12.5.1 and Xcode 13.4.1 ,
Build version 13F100. I am still facing the same issue. I tried erasing the pip cache too.

Answer (score 2):

libssh2 is installed, but Apple has depreciated its use in newer MacOS versions in favor of its own libraries, hence why it cannot be found. In your error, the package is looking for libssh2 in `/usr/lib/libssh2.1.dylib`, which does not contain the dylibs. You will need to find where they were installed (with brew 3.6.19 the default install path is `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/` on Monterey 12.6.2)

The following command worked for me:

```
 export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path to libssh2.1.dylib, 1.1, 1.0 etc/
```

For my system homebrew installed libssh2 and the .dylib files in the following path...

```
 export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libssh2/1.10.0/lib/
```

You can also place this export statement in your .bashrc or .zshrc so that you won't have to define it each time you restart the shell.

I found many of the solutions on other forums for this issue are outdated/do no work, it is possible this may not work in a future version.